# how to check one string value with few numbers in when condition in drools file

Tags: drools

```
rule "CHECK SCHEME FOR PBKAS"
   when
      item : scheme_s1 (itemgroup==0185 || itemgroup==0125)

   then
     item.setSchemecode("E15-RETGOOMZ_AS");
     helper(drools);

end
```

in above code, `itemgroup` is a string variable in which value taking from user. and I have already some `itemgroup` value like 1050,2018,2013 n etc ..so i want to check `itemgroup` value taking from user with lots of number which already I have as a `itemgroup`.

how can I do this in when condition or any another way.
please help

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where do you have the values you want to check. If you have them inside a Collection, as a global (i.e. `itemgroupsToCheck`), then you can write something like this:

```
global List itemgroupsToCheck;


rule "CHECK SCHEME FOR PBKAS"
   when
      item : scheme_s1 (itemgroup memberOf itemgroupsToCheck)
   then
     item.setSchemecode("E15-RETGOOMZ_AS");
     helper(drools);

end
```

If the collection comes from another Fact, then you can write something like this:

```
rule "CHECK SCHEME FOR PBKAS"
   when
      YourFact($itemgroupsToCheck: itemgroupsToCheck)
      item : scheme_s1 (itemgroup memberOf $itemgroupsToCheck)
   then
     item.setSchemecode("E15-RETGOOMZ_AS");
     helper(drools);

end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: yes . I create one list in my java class file which name is demo in which I stored my groups no. but problem is , the value of variable itemgroup  which is taking from user is stored in one arraylist in java file. and I created another list in same file for storing my group no in that list. now in ksession.insert(itemgroup) I passed object of first arraylist which having user item group. so in drool file I got the error " unable to find class list"  .what can I do.. please help

Comment: can I create my collection in drool file in which I will store my item groups